# Get Function constructor to work with arguments?

Tags: javascript

*I'm doing some testing with Function constructor , just for learning)*

so here is the story :

As `Function constructor`  is the *preferred* way over `eval` , I've managed [**(jsbin)**](http://jsbin.com/upazac/5/edit) to get my `regex` variable by its name

```
var my1Pattern=/\d/ig; 
var my2Pattern=/\w/ig;
var my3Pattern=/\d+/ig;


var f=new Function( "return my"+3+"Pattern"); //3 or 2 or 1 , doesn't matter .

doWork(f()) //"[object RegExp]"


function doWork(r)
{
   alert(Object.prototype.toString.apply(r))
}
```

However  , I want the *number* to be sent *as a parameter* to the Function ctor.

And so, I've tried replacing : ([**jsbin#2**](http://jsbin.com/upazac/8/edit))

```
var f=new Function("a", "return a")( "my"+5+"Pattern")
 doWork(f)
```

But it alerts `"string"` . (which is correct because i'm actually sending a string).

**Question :**

How can I get *first* code to work **with** `Function constructor` parameters?

**In other words ,I want to be able to send a number as a param/string to the Function constructor , so it will return the regex.**

Comment: The `Function` constructor is hardly better than `eval`.  Whoever recommended it over `eval` is a freaking idiot.  The *preferred* way is to not be running strings as JS in the first place.

Comment: @cHao  Function constructor  dont have any access to global variable while eval has.

Comment: @cHao `Function` constructors are better in that they prevent the access to the current scope - which is exactly what the asker is trying to achieve

Comment: Also  this is how jquery parse json if JSON obj is not to the rescue.

Comment: Arrays can't be used? I've never encountered the need to use a function constructor (or eval).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The fact that jQuery does it doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak it is for learning's purpose. ( the function ctor). I shall mention it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Can you show us some code for this that works with `eval`?I'm still not sure what you want to do. Or is it `return [my1Pattern, my2Pattern, my3Patter][a-1]`?

Comment: I'm afraid #2 can't be done. The best you can do is `f = function(x){return window[x]})`.

Comment: @Bergi there are no array involve here. I just want to get the regex which curresponds to `my[X]PAttern`.

Comment: I think the only way is to use `var f=new Function("a", "return a")( (new Function("return my"+3+"Pattern;")() );`

Comment: I must say: "stay away from function constructors and `eval`. There's nothing interesting to be seen here."

Comment: @JanDvorak Come on my friend , it is for learning purpose. Im not building spaceship.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do here?

Comment: @jcubic your comment is the only answer which answer my question. no matter what are the complications.as I stated -  this is  learning question. please convert it to a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way is to use another function.

```
var f=new Function("a", "return a")( (new Function("return my"+3+"Pattern;")() );
doWork(f)
```

Comment: Not saying it is best practice solution but it is the only one which answer my exact question.

Answer (score 2):

*Simply don't.* That is horrid.

You haven't told us what you're trying to do, but I believe that it's something along these lines:

```
var myPattern = [
   /\d/ig,
   /\w/ig,
   /\d+/ig
];

/** Apply my ith regex to str */
var f = function(str, i) {
   return str.apply(myPattern[i]);
};

console.log(f("hello!", 0));
console.log(f("hello!", 1));
console.log(f("hello!", 2));
```

You can complain as much as you like that you don't wish to use arrays, but that doesn't change the fact that ***this* is the correct approach**, and the manner recommended to you by *whomever that was* is ludicrously silly.

***We shall not obtain references to objects through string versions of their names, neither using `eval` nor using the `Function` constructor.***

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand Function constructors better.

Comment: A better approach would be to use object properties in square brackets. such as `myArray["lala"+"1"]` which is preferred over you r solution which is based on indexes. but again , Im trying to use Function constructor arguments ! something like `Function ("a","alert(a)");` I know what i'm asking and why. I know the other ways of doing it , **but as I stated , it is for learning purpose.**

Comment: @Royi Why would that be "a better approach"? Here's a thrilling notion: _learn the **right** way to do things_.

Comment: Because if someone pushes another item between it wont work , where object properties will work. Howver , you are refusing to recognize the fact which i want to learn  Function constructor implementations.

Comment: @Royi: Yes, I am. And if you asked me to teach you how to extract my eyes from their sockets, I would refuse you that too. (Co-incidentally, the two are not all that different.)

Comment: Well , they are. if some other developer in your team insert another item into the array and suddenly things stop working , well it's a beginner mistake. putting it as an object property is the right way to go (and array is not). anyway , we have a disagreement.

Comment: @Royi The object key `"lala"+"1"` obfuscates your code and does little else. Using meaningful keys? Sure, maybe.

Comment: It was just an example ...( to prevent indexes problem when someone in the future modify your array as in your answer.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir It was a testcase. The code locality means no-one is going to modify that array and break some reliance on specific indices, because _you should not ever have reliance on specific indices_. If you need to be able to refer to **specific** regexes then, yes, map them to string keys. All the rest of my comments were referring to your strange need to learn how to do a silly thing (create functions from strings).

Comment: IMO , it is not a silly thing to know and to test Function constructor.  ( not that I use it  , but do want to learn . and When I'm learning how to use something I dig very deep.).

Answer (score 2):

The complement to

```
function (a) {
    return eval("my"+a+"Pattern");
}
```

would be

```
function (a) {
    return new Function("return my"+a+"Pattern")();
}
```

But you know not to use any of them :-)

Comment: your second solution is the closest to my question. I'm wondering if the (a) param can be used in the Function ctor param. ( as you know , we can do : `Function ("a","alert(a)");`